# How to display both Depth and Color video image with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, realsense

I'm pretty new with OpenCV & Intel Realsense device.
I can see many examples displaying only Depth video or Color video, but i really can't find any example displaying both in real-time.

I have no idea (should i multi thread?) how to make it. So anybody have any hint??

Comment: you can show 2 different images with the imshow, just remember to change the string part (first parameter), otherwise it will be drawn in one window and the latest one wins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you need to do, in a nutshell:

a) Include required headers

```
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <librealsense2/rs.hpp>
#include "../cv-helpers.hpp"
```

b) RealSense data to OpenCV Mat

```
auto data = pipe.wait_for_frames();
data = align_to.process(data);

auto color_frame = data.get_color_frame();
auto depth_frame = data.get_depth_frame();

auto color_mat = frame_to_mat(color_frame);
auto depth_mat = frame_to_mat(depth_frame);
```

c) Display color_mat and depth_mat

```
imshow("color",color_mat);
imshow("depth",depth_mat);
```